# Quickly find a java class in a windows folder

Tags: java

Given the class name: `com.example.MyClass` (alternatively with '`/`'s instead) How can i quickly determine whether a java class exists in a folder containing a bunch of jars/class files?

Currently my only solution is to open them with an archive inspector (7zip) and search the directories.

anything better than this would be very helpful.

**EDIT:** Also I'm looking for something faster than creating a new project in an IDE, adding the folder and using it's tools to find the class.

**UPDATE:** If this question doesn't get a useful answer, I'm [building a utility called javaclassfinder](https://github.com/thenaglecode/javaclassfinder) and there is a 'questions for comment' section in the README.md where people can help me answer some questions necessary for constructing the utility. also you are welcome to comment and suggest means of implementation!

**UPDATE:** user3819021's solution is helpful and works although it depends on the existence of cygwin, If anyone knows of a windows only solution it would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a gap in the market that it would be useful to have a small Java app for.

Comment: good call @Stewart, I'm thinking a menu context item, what do you think? the amount of times I've found myself asking this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed on your machine, you can try the following code:

```
find <your root path> -name '*.jar' | while read file; do unzip -l "$file" | grep -q <search file> && echo $file; done
```

`<search file>` should be something like `/path/YourClass.class` or just `YourClass.class`.

Comment: thats just for jars, there could also be war/ear s

Comment: @thenaglecode You'd just need to modify '*.jar' for the ear/war files. They are just JAR files with some extra info.

Comment: Another issue with this is that it won't find standalone `.class` files that aren't in a JAR. The trivial fix would just be to prepend `find <your root path> -name <search file>;` to the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Open a powershell prompt and run

```
gci -LiteralPath "C:\work\src\javastuff" -Filter *.class | ? { $_.FullName -match "my.package.SomeClass.class" }
```

-if you just want a list of full path and filename, append this bit:

```
| % { $_.FullName }
```

Comment: I tried it with a class i knew was there and it didn't work :(. looks like it doesn't traverse zip files.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will search the whole classpath for a particular class. With no arguments it will dump every class it finds and then you can pipe to grep or redirect to a file. It looks inside jars...

Usage: `WhichClass` or `WhichClass package.name` (note no `.class`)

Apologies for the lack of comments ...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public final class WhichClass {

  private WhichClass() {
  }

  static Vector<String> scratchVector;

  public static void main(final String[] argv) {
    Vector v;

    if ((argv.length == 0) || "-all".equals(argv[0])) {
      v = findClass(null);
    } else {
      v = findClass(argv[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(v.elementAt(i));
    }
  }

  static String className(final String classFile) {
    return classFile.replace('/', '.').substring(0, classFile.length() - ".class".length());
  }

  static Vector findClass(final String className) {
    if (className != null) {
      scratchVector = new Vector<String>(5);
    } else {
      scratchVector = new Vector<String>(5000);
    }

    findClassInPath(className, setupBootClassPath());
    findClassInPath(className, setupClassPath());

    return scratchVector;
  }

  static void findClassInPath(final String className, final StringTokenizer path) {
    while (path.hasMoreTokens()) {
      String pathElement = path.nextToken();

      File pathFile = new File(pathElement);

      if (pathFile.isDirectory()) {
        try {
          if (className != null) {
            String pathName = className.replace('.', System.getProperty("file.separator").charAt(0)) + ".class";

            findClassInPathElement(pathName, pathElement, pathFile);
          } else {
            findClassInPathElement(className, pathElement, pathFile);
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      } else if (pathFile.exists()) {
        try {
          if (className != null) {
            String pathName = className.replace('.', '/') + ".class";

            ZipFile  zipFile  = new ZipFile(pathFile);
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(pathName);
            if (zipEntry != null) {
              scratchVector.addElement(pathFile + "(" + zipEntry + ")");
            }
          } else {
            ZipFile     zipFile = new ZipFile(pathFile);
            Enumeration entries = zipFile.entries();

            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
              String entry = entries.nextElement().toString();

              if (entry.endsWith(".class")) {
                String name = className(entry);

                scratchVector.addElement(pathFile + "(" + entry + ")");
              }
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e + " while working on " + pathFile);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static void findClassInPathElement(final String pathName, final String pathElement, final File pathFile)
    throws IOException {
    String[] list = pathFile.list();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      File file = new File(pathFile, list[i]);

      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        findClassInPathElement(pathName, pathElement, file);
      } else if (file.exists() && (file.length() != 0) && list[i].endsWith(".class")) {
        String classFile = file.toString().substring(pathElement.length() + 1);

        String name = className(classFile);

        if (pathName != null) {
          if (classFile.equals(pathName)) {
            scratchVector.addElement(file.toString());
          }
        } else {
          scratchVector.addElement(file.toString());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static StringTokenizer setupBootClassPath() {
    String classPath = System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path");
    String separator = System.getProperty("path.separator");

    return new StringTokenizer(classPath, separator);
  }

  static StringTokenizer setupClassPath() {
    String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String separator = System.getProperty("path.separator");

    return new StringTokenizer(classPath, separator);
  }
}
```